# How do I disable public access to a jamon admin page?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jamon

How do I disable public access to the Jamon admin jsp page in a Spring / Java EE web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spring security](http://www.springsource.org/spring-security) is one way.

Standard Java EE security is another. It's described in detail in the [Servlet specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315) and you can search the web for something like "Java EE servlet security" for examples.